# Which can be a better iteration method?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, iterator

Scenario:

**java swing custom control:**
        1 Panel and inside 150 Check boxes[] arrays (dynamically created). Capable of returning the selected check box's index as int[]. This 150 is a dynamic number.

To return this int[], which below method will be a better option. Or any else method is there to follow?

**Method 1:**
     Add ItemListener to each checkbox and add/remove selected index value to a arraylist based on the check box selected state. And use this list in the function and form the int[] to return.

**Method 2:**
     Create a boolean array with 150 size.
     Add ItemListener to each checkbox and assign value true/false to the boolean[index], based on the selected state. And use this list in the function and form the int[] to return.

**Method 3:**
      When calling the int[] returning function, use a for loop and find the selected checkbox and form the int[] and return.

Comment: A UI with 150 check-boxes would drive me insane O_o.

Comment: Just another implementation of Minesweeper!

Comment: In terms of running time 150 items is very little, it probably makes very little discernible difference how you iterate across them. (Considering that this is a single-user desktop system we're talking about.) However in terms of user experience, a UI with potentially 150 checkboxes sounds like hell.

Comment: Apart from the inconvenience of an overcrowded UI, the one thing I'd worry about is thread safety. If you don't use multiple threads (i.e. everything runs off the Event Dispatcher Thread), there's nothing extra you need to do, but if you want to be able to call your function from different threads, you need to make sure the values are visible.

Comment: As other users before me mentioned a UI with so many Ccheckboxes are insane :) .. but if you insist on that  i would prefer Method 3 as  the better solution, if the checking of all checkboxes should done after a period of time.

Comment: What is the need? Is having a X by Y array of integers really needed? A list of x,y coordinates of checked (or unchecked, depending on the need) boxes would be enough and no need for iteration over X times Y values that are not useful. Edit: Even if the array is 1 dimension, keeping only values of checked or unchecked boxes could be enough.

Comment: Keeping a [Bitset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) would probably be the most efficient way.

Comment: `JTable` comes to mind

Comment: @MadProgrammer...Yes i also thought of the JTable. Anyway it is also going to have the 150 check boxes. so any difference is there between this two?